# How to convert a text into image and then rotate it vertically

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, rotation

Does someone know the best approach on how to convert a text into image and rotate it vertically? 
Or do you have a code on how to do that?

Any web programming language would do (PHP, Javascript, etc..)

I writing a program in php and javascript wherein I let people type in their name in a text input and it will be converted into image, and that image will be rotated.

Hope this info helps.

Comment: You may not need to create an image for this. Check out http://flipmytext.com/ and take a look at their JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you familiar with the GD Library in PHP?

[GD Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)

Comment: No, I am not familiar with that, Let me read on that one. Thanks though! :)

Comment: Actually, I already used the DG Library, but the problem here is when the length of the text is long, the text would become distorted. I wanted to upload a screenshot of that but I don't know how to upload it here in the comment section. :)

Comment: Well certainly your application would require more than just the image creation functions, such as manipulating the text submitted by the user so that it is of a certain length or less, or cropping, breaking, or trimming it.  Placing text in a, let's say, 400x200px image would require that only xx characters of xx font size would be allowed, and if it were too long, it would either be reduced in size or broken into multiple lines.

Answer (score 3):

PHP with the GD library can do this.  The [imagettftext()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) function will add text to an image and [imagerotate()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php) function can rotate it by an arbitrary angle.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it on the client side using *HTML5*, *CSS3*, and of course *Javascript*.

1. You can first draw text, images, videos, anything you want on a `<canvas>`.
2. Then you can use [this api](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/), *canvas2image*, and turn it into a dataurl (base64).
3. **a)** Finally put it a `<img>` and apply some *CSS3* on it:
   　`-webkit-transform:rotateY(45deg);`　 <-- For Webkit browsers
   　`-moz-transform:rotateY(45deg);`　 <-- For Firefox
   　`-o-transform:rotateY(45deg);`　 <-- For Opera
   　`-ms-transform:rotateY(45deg);`　 <--Not sure about this if this exists
   　`transform:rotateY(45deg);`　 <-- Original
   **b)** Or you can rotate it in the `<canvas>` in ***`step #2`*** if you prefer.

Learn more about the `<canvas>` tag on [MDN Canvas Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/canvas_tutorial).
The HTML5 and the Javascript part is ***IE9-safe***. :D

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read my article at CodeProject: *Vertical Labels in Web Pages* - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/VerticalLabel.aspx

Whatever you need it in web pages or just in a bitmap object, you'll find the solution there.

Comment: Thanks for being honest about your interest in the link. This would be a great answer though if you could summarize the key points of your linked article within the answer, so that the link complements the answer rather than being the only content of the answer.